Improving under sink setup with drain close to sink bottom
Any suggestions on how I can improve the messy under sink set up below?
RO and dishwasher drain need to connect above drain level
Is the flexible P-Trap good enough for permanent installations?


There is so much wrong there.  None of the other drains connecting to it are trapped, and the flex tube is totally wrong.
The right way to fix this is to open up the wall to access the drain pipe to lower the stub out of the wall.  Assuming it's vertical, of course.  If the pipe behind the wall goes sideways, you'd need to chase it to where it goes down.
After that, you need a proper non-flexy P-trap, with proper wye connections upstream of the trap for the dishwasher and RO drain.
